# How to display every step of recursion function in js?

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a recursion function. And have  three divs in HTML  like monitors (slot_a, slot_b, slot_c). Algorithm is similar to Tower of Hanoi. 
So in each  monitor I want to see what happens in each slot. For this I use innerHTML. But I can get only the same text in each slot. 
What to do to make them different?

```
const moveCranes = function(plate, slot_a, slot_b, slot_c) {
    moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_a, slot_c, slot_b);
    port_a.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
    port_b.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
    port_c.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
    moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_b, slot_a, slot_c);
}
}
moveCranes(input.value,"slot_a","slot_b","slot_c");
```

Comment: is the first call `moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_a, slot_c, slot_b);` really necessary? also, have a check condition first to check when to stop and then do your execution else it will give you a **error of maximum call stack reached**.

Comment: @vikscool, thanks. Can You edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
port_a = document.getElementById("port_a");
step = 1;
$row = $("<div class='row'>"+
          "<div class='col-xs-3 plate'><p>Plate</p></div>"+
          "<div class='col-xs-3 a'><p>A</p></div>"+
          "<div class='col-xs-3 b'><p>B</p></div>"+
          "<div class='col-xs-3 c'><p>C</p></div>"+
          +"</div>");
$container = $("#container");
const moveCranes = function(plate, slot_from, slot_to, slot_aux) {
 if(plate == 1){
        let $temp = $row.clone();
        $temp.find('.plate').append("<h1>"+plate+"</h1>");
        $temp.find('.'+slot_from).append("<h1>-</h1>");
        $temp.find('.'+slot_to).append("<h1>+</h1>");
        $container.append($temp);
        port_a.innerHTML += step++ + ". Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_from + " to " + slot_to + "..." + "</br>";
  }
  else{
        moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_from, slot_aux, slot_to);
        let $temp = $row.clone();
        $temp.find('.plate').append("<h1>"+plate+"</h1>");
        $temp.find('.'+slot_from).append("<h1>-</h1>");
        $temp.find('.'+slot_to).append("<h1>+</h1>");
        $container.append($temp);
        port_a.innerHTML += step++ + ". Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_from + " to " + slot_to + "..." + "</br>";
        moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_aux, slot_to, slot_from);
    }
}

moveCranes(3,"a","b","c");
```

```css
.row{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  
</div>

<div id="port_a"></div>
```

Comment: I have changed your input.value to hardcoded value 3, otherwise I have to add more code which is out of this context. Plz change accordingly.

Comment: @ Aagam Jain, thanks, why didn't you change port_b.innerHTML, port_c.innerHTML?

Comment: For that I just need to create 3 divs. So I added.
Does it work for you?

Comment: @ Aagam Jain work,but they show the same. But I need them to show only what happens in every div. There are different events

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Plz explain.

Comment: For Tower of Hanoi, Your Logic was wrong. I updated the answer. Plz check.

Comment: The function performs the algorithm to move plates. In step 1, plate1 moves from slot_a to slot_c. It must be shown in the  div a and c.  Then plate 2 moves from slot_a to slot_c. It must be shown in div b and c. Rest one div will be always empty

Comment: Ok I got it. Trying for solution. :)

Comment: ,say please what about port_b and_c?

Comment: ,thank u for help. But sorry,could u return it in native js,because my task is to use native?